# Get clicked anchor element's id property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When user click this element, I want catch id data in controller or in OnActionExecuting method in ActionFilter class.

How I can do this?

In view:

```
<a id="123" href="AreaName/ControllerName">TEST</a>
```

Comment: you should go for `Jquery` to pass the id value to controller

Comment: i can not use `Jquery` because it will be simple solution.

Comment: OnActionExecuting method will be invoked when request is already received by the server, you cannot modify it after that. You'll have to either use jquery or set appropriate URL while rendering this anchor tag. If you have some model variable that sets your ID then you can use  href="AreaName/ControllerName/" +@model.id  in your razor view

Answer (score 0):

You could try this...

In Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new HomeViewModel { Id = 123 };
        return View(model);
    }
    public void RecordClick(int id)
    {
        int incomingId = id;
    }
```

In View:

```
    @Html.ActionLink("Link Text", "RecordClick", "Home", new { id = @Model.Id }, null)
```

Generated HTML:

```
    <a href="/AreaName/Home/RecordClick/123">Link Text</a>
```

Upon clicking link, id value will be sent to RecordClick action.

Comment: Link's id property not setting by controller.you think it is random number.

Comment: I think I may have misunderstood your goal here; are you wanting to get the id of the control that was clicked or were you just using the id attribute of the html element to store a value that represented a user's id?

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="~/AreaName/ControllerName?userid=3">TEST</a>
```

your controller

```
    [HttpGet] 
    public ActionResult Index(int userid)
    {
       return View();
    }
```

if you debug you should have that value

Comment: Link's id property not setting by controller.you think it is random number.